# Keeping data consistency with multiple clients using nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency, database

I am creating a nodejs web server that uses mongodb, and I've encountered several situations where the data could be end up in a inconsistent state when multiple requests are being processed concurrently. For example, when creating a user, it would first check that the username does not exists, then it will create the user. But there would be a problem if, after it checked that the username does not exist but before creating the user, another client creates a user with that username. How can I prevent this problem? Is this easier to solve using a different database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB allows you to specify a unique constraint on an index.

So you can set unique index on a username, it will check a unique username on insertion time. Your concern will resolve through this feature

```
db.collection.createIndex( { username: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

You can get more information from this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/)

Thanks